# Relays for Logic - Current and debouncing?

Tags: digital-logic, current, relay, debounce

Im just doing a little project for fun using relays to build logic circuits, and just have a few "thinking outloud" type questions...

1) Any contacts that can make a loop back to the power supply would need a resistor on that path, otherwise when the contacts connect its effectively shorting out the power supply?

2) How much of a problem if any would contact bouncing be when wanting to use relays for logic. Even at "slow" speeds would this be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Any contacts that can make a loop back to the power supply would need a resistor on that path, otherwise when the contacts connect its effectively shorting out the power supply?

Of course, you have to add resistors to the contacts or a resistor in the path of the main supply.

> How much of a problem if any would contact bouncing be when wanting to use relays for logic. Even at "slow" speeds would this be a problem.

The severity of the problem depends on what king of signal you are transfering through the switch, if it is a clock then you will be in big trouble but if it just a logic state then it will just take longet to stabilize, this can be a problem or have no effect, depends on what you are doing.